Homotopy and Homology groups of two disks glued with twists
The problem is from a qualifying exam. The space $X$ is constructed by gluing two disks along their boundaries using the gluing maps $z \mapsto z^2$ and $z \mapsto z^3$.

Compute $\pi_1(X), H_1(X, \mathbb{Z}), H_2(X, \mathbb{Z})$.
Is $X$ homeomorphic to $S^2$?

I am interpreting the disks are $D^2$. My intuition is to extend the two spheres to open sets, homeomorphic to $D_2$ that form a cover, say $\{A,B\}$ of $X$. Since each of $A,B$ has trivial $\pi_1$, SVK will imply that $X$ has trivial fundamental group. For the homology group, Mayer Vietoris can be applied to obtain information about the homology groups. I am not sure if the idea of constructing this cover is correct, i.e. I am not certain whether the two disks can be "extended" to obtain an open cover of $X$ as proposed above. Even if it can be done, I am not sure if the open sets will be homeomorphic to $D^2$, or some other simply connected space.
For the second question, my guess is that it is correct, but I am not sure how to prove/disprove it.

What's your question, specifically? Are you asking for a solution? A hint?

My question is really whether the two disks can be extended to a open cover as I proposed, and if not, then I am asking for a solution to the problem.

Sorry, struggling to understand the construction - is $X$ the disjoint union of two quotients of disks, one under $f:z\mapsto z^2$ and the other under $g:z\mapsto z^3$? If not, and the disks are glued to one another, how can they be glued along $f$ and $g$ simulatenously?

@Tom The construction is perhaps better described as "attaching two disks to (a single copy of) $S^1$ via the maps $z \to z^2$ and $z \to z^3$, respectively."

@BenSteffan Gotcha! Thank you

I would ask that you edit the question to incorporate the corrected wording suggested by  @BenSteffan.

Let me just give you a hint to get started. You're wrong off the bat; the two discs are not really discs. Note $z\mapsto z^2$ is not injective: the maps $D^2\to X$ are not embeddings, the two disc-images are not homeomorphic with a disc. The first is actually homeomorphic with $\Bbb RP^2$, if you view $X$ as a common circle $S^1$ with two discs attached via those two maps $z\mapsto z^2$.
So, we cannot cover $X$ with simply connected sets in the way you describe; if we thicken the discs slightly (rigorously, take the image of one $D^2\to X$ and union it with the image of some $U\hookrightarrow D^2\to X$ where $U$ is something like $D^2\setminus\{0\}$, say) then these form an open cover $\{A,B\}$ of $X$ where $A,B$ are homotopy equivalent to the discs $Y_1,Y_2$ whose boundaries are twisted by $z\mapsto z^2,z^3$ respectively. You can use Seifert Van Kampen to conclude those homotopy groups are $\Bbb Z_2,\Bbb Z_3$; $A\cap B$ deformation retracts onto something homeomorphic to $S^1$. The homomorphisms $\Bbb Z=\pi_1(S^1)\to\Bbb Z_2,\Bbb Z_3$ pick out the generators of those groups. I messed this up the first time round (thanks to Ben Steffan for the comment), so let's be clear on why that is. The loop winding once around $S^1$ can be parametrised via the map $q:D^2\to Y_1$ as $q(\lambda(t))$ where $\lambda(t)$ sweeps out a semicircle (so $q(\lambda(t))$ sweeps out a whole circle) and this is the generating loop of $Y_1$. It's the same for $Y_2$.
Now, $\Bbb Z_2\ast_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Z_3=0$ here. Why? It's $\langle\alpha,\beta\,|\,\alpha^2,\beta^3,\alpha\beta^{-1}\rangle$ which comes down to $\langle\alpha\,|\alpha^2,\alpha^3\rangle\cong\langle\alpha\,|\,\alpha\rangle=0$. Hence $\pi_1(X)$ is trivial and $H_1(X)$ is trivial too. For a different perspective, you can also imagine that $D^2\to Y_1\subset X$ and $D^2\to Y_2\subset X$ map the generating loop of $\partial D^2$ to $2$ and $3$ times the generating loop of $S^1\simeq Y_1\cap Y_2$ (so these values are killed, are nullhomotopic); so we have to think about $\pi_1(S^1)/(2,3)$, which is the zero group.
Try and work out $H_2(X)$ now, but bear in mind that the "discs" are not really discs. You can use Mayer-Vietoris with my open cover (which is also your open cover). Thinking about how we figured out $\pi_1$, you can firstly understand what the kernel of $H_1(A\cap B)\to H_1(A)\oplus H_1(B)$ is. As for whether or not $X\cong S^2$, consider the classic technique of deleting a point; chosen carefully, after deletion $X$ would become homotopy equivalent to something, and $S^2$ to something else.

@BenSteffan You're right, I messed up the calculation of the induced homomorphisms $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z_2$. Of course they pick out the generators, but I imagined the central loop as coming from $\partial D^2\subset D^2$ and thus being nullhomotopic (which is wrong of course!).

Now it looks good to me! :)

@Fshrike Thank you, I am just have trouble understanding why the homomorphism from the free group onto $\pi_1(X)$ is trivial. In particular, I do not see why $\alpha^2$ and $\beta^3$ are relators.

@MutasimMim If $\alpha$ generates $\Bbb Z_2$ and $\beta$ generates $\Bbb Z_3$, then $\alpha^2,\beta^3$ are trivial. Then because the map $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z_2,\Bbb Z_3$ send $1$ to $\alpha,\beta$, the definition of amalgamated free product (which is what we use in SvK) tells us we must identify them. That’s where I get my relations from.

As FShrike points out in their answer, your approach does not work.
While the approach using van Kampen and Mayer-Vietoris is nice, let me give a slightly different approach.
To compute $\pi_1(X)$, recall that a standard way to construct, for any group $G$, a space $X_G$ with fundamental group $\pi_1 X_G \cong G$ is to choose a presentation of $G$ with generators $\{g_i\}_{i \in I}$, take the 1-skeleton of $X_G$ to be $\bigvee_{i \in I} S^1_i$ (here the subscript is just for indexing purposes) so that $\pi_1(\operatorname{sk}_1 X_G)$ can be identified with the free group on the $g_i$ and then attach 2-cells along a representative of the class in $\pi_1(\operatorname{sk}_1 X_G)$ representing a given relation, viewed as a word in the $g_i$ and their inverses, for all relations in the chosen presentation (in case this is unfamiliar, one proves that $\pi_1 X_G \cong G$ via what's essentially a generalization of FShrike's van Kampen argument, see Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology," Cor. 1.28 for a reference).
How is this useful here? Well, $X$ can be described as the space obtained from attaching two 2-cells to $S^1$ along a map of degree 2 and a map of degree 3, respectively, which follows precisely the recipe above "in reverse:" You start out with $\operatorname{sk}_1 X = S^1$, so $\pi_1 X \cong \mathbb{Z}$ generated by some element $z$, and then kill the words $z^2$ and $z^3$, whence $\pi_1 X \cong \langle z \mid z^2, z^3 \rangle = 0$.
To calculate homology, we'll take a slightly different point of view: Note that if we restrict our attention for a second to only attaching a single cell via some map $f\colon S^1 \to S^1$, the resulting space $C_f$ is by definition the mapping cone of $f$. Now for such a mapping cone we always have an exact sequence
$$
   0 \to H_2(C_f) \to H_1(S^1) \overset{f_*}{\to} H_1(S^1) \to H_1(C_f) \to 0
$$
where the zero at the left is the group $H_2(S^1) = 0$ and the one on the right follows from the fact that $f_*\colon H_0(S^1) \to H_0(S^1)$ is the identity (for different spaces the sequence may of course be longer). Thus, if $f$ is the map $f(z) = z^2$, say, then $f_*$ in the sequence above is multiplication by 2 and therefore $H_1(C_f) \cong \mathbb{Z} / 2$, and $H_2(C_f) = 0$ (which, as FShrike observes, one could also see directly from the fact that $C_f \cong \mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^2$).
To go from this to the $X$ in your example is then simply taking another mapping cone, that of the map $z \to z^3$ composed with the inclusion into $C_f$. I, too, leave it as an exercise for you to finish the computation.
Finally, if you know about cellular homology, the construction of $X$ very conveniently gives you all the differentials in the cellular chain complex, so you can just crank out the computation directly.

The point of these techniques, apart from simply being more tools in the toolbox, is that they're often "cleaner" than things like van Kampen or Mayer-Vietoris. You don't need to worry about choosing open sets and their intersections, or what something deformation retracts onto. Of course, the downside is that these techniques are only applicable in "nice" situations, although one finds that nice situations are rather common in algebraic topology.
Here's another relatively general technique regarding question 2: Note that $S^2$ is a manifold, in particular it is locally euclidean. Questions about whether some space $X$ that is obtained as some sort of gluing or quotient, especially when the quotient isn't "uniform" across the entire space, is homeomorphic to a manifold can often be resolved in the negative by showing that some point doesn't have a euclidean neighborhood of the appropriate dimension. Another thing that often works is taking a needle to the spaces in question: Poke a hole (i.e. take out a point), and if the resulting spaces are not homeomorphic, then neither are the original spaces (though this does make implicit use of transitivity of homeomorphisms on manifolds).
